# Type mismatch: cannot convert from FireFoxDriver to WebDriver

Tags: selenium

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNyVM.png)

```
package demo;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FacebookRegistration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the typo in your IDE? You've imported `FirefoxDriver` and try to instantiate `FireFoxDriver`

Answer (score 0):

You have exactly 2 problems in your code as follows :

- **`import`** :

  As you have used `import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;` on similar lines you have to use :

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  ```
- **`System.setProperty()`** :

  While you work with **`Selenium v3.x.x`** you have to download the latest **`geckodriver`** binary from this [`link`](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), save it in your system and provide the absolute path of the **`geckodriver`** binary through **`System.setProperty()`** line as follows :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
  ```